# Is it possible to reference a Foreign Key in a different database in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to create a model and a migration for that model in Laravel 4.2. All of my Laravel apps use the same MySQL database called `laravel`. However, we also have another database (on the same server), called `main_db` that contains a `users` table, which I would like to use for the source of a few foreign keys in my own `laravel_users` table in the `laravel` database.

According to the Laravel documentation, I would designate a foreign key with this code:

```
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

But I believe this assumes that the `'users'` table exists within the same database.

Is it possible to do trans-database foreign keys in Laravel? Would I have to first create a model that uses the `users` table from `main_db`? And is it possible to set up two different database connections in the `app/config/database.php`?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Cross database foreign keys hasn't much to do with Laravel actually. The real question is if the database does support it. And MySQL (at least with InnoDB) does support foreign key constraints accross multiple databases. You just have to specify the database with the dot notation: `db.table`.

Regarding the Laravel schema builder, this should work:

```
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('main_db.users');
//                                                ^^^^^^^
```

If you get an error, check if the column types are the same.
(You can't reference varchar to int or vice versa, keys have to be of same type).

Comment: Oh wow. I love it when things come together that cleanly. Thank you very much. Just to clarify though, would I then have to add dot notation for each database going forward? I.e. all of my previous Laravel models would have to use `laravel.xxxx` from here on out...?

Comment: You're welcome. No, you only have to specify the db if it's different from the db that the table you're adding the key to is in.

Comment: Can you tell me where the method `references` is defined? `Blueprint::foreign` returns `Fluent` and this does not contain `references`. So where can I find it?!

Comment: @scarface It's not explicitly defined anywhere. The `Fluent` class accepts all method calls and essentially just sets key value pairs internally. [Source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Support/Fluent.php#L141)

Comment: @lukasgeiter Thank you. I did not consider that magic method.

Comment: it will work. @cchapman you should call the db name like this
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on(env('DB_DATABASE').'.users');

Answer (score 25):

For future reference if you ever change the name of the database this will not work.  It is best to grab the name of the database by the database definition.

config/database.php

```
'auth_database' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'strict' => false,
    'engine' => null,
],
```

Then in your migration file:

```
Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $db = DB::connection('auth_database')->getDatabaseName();

    $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles');
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on(new Expression($db . '.users'));
});
```

Comment: I used `->on(config('database.connections.mysql.database') . '.users')` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Answer of @**lukasgeiter** worked for me with following two changes:

1- I changed both database engines to **InnoDB**.

2- I had to set the foreign key to be an **Unsigned integer** in the migration file as the reference was an unsigned integer and was the primary key.

```
$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->change();
```